# How to configure Webstorm to run *.spec.ts using Mocha for brand new Vue project

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webstorm, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I can't figure out how to properly setup my WebStorm environment with a brand new created Vue project using the Vue CLI 3...

Repro step:

1. `npm install -g @vue/cli` (my version is latest 3.3.0)
2. New project in WebStorm
3. Select Vue.js
4. Specify the Vue/cli directory (For me it was /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli)
5. Select *Manually select features*
6. Select all except PWA (Babel, Typescript, Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter/Formatter Unit/E2E Testing)
7. Default configs until for testing
8. Select *Mocha + Chai* for unit tests
9. Select *Nightwatch* for E2E tests
10. Config files in dedicated files

Once the project is created, if I right click on the generated unit test file it tries to run it using Jest...

I tried to manually create a a config using Mocha, but can't figure it out... I tried adding *Compile TypeScript* as a before launch step, tried adding `--require ts-node/register` after doing `npm i -D ts-node` but without success...

Answer (score 2):

Running Mocha tests with vue cli is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-34938](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34938) to be notified on any progress with this feature.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Hopefully they will support it soon. Until then, any workaround so we can debug our mocha tests with WebStorm?

Comment: you can try running them using Node.js configuration